# Stack divs next to each other and align the divs underneath accordingly

Tags: html, css

I have divs like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
</div>
```

And I want to align the divs in a **3** column design, like this:

[image]

So the height of the divs depend on the content inside.

### What I've tried so far

I tried adding the `display:inline-block` approach and `verticle-align:top;` but all my results ended up with something like this:

[image]

What is the solution to stack them properly underneath each other like the *first* picture? Similar to how pinterest stacks the pin boxes...

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcwnvx12/1/) for testing.

Comment: I think you will need to use masonry https://masonry.desandro.com/. Some one may have a flex solution, but I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
  <div class="inner">text</div>
</div>

.inner {
  background:lightblue;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29%;
}
```

The width depends on your own styling structure.